# Drag and drop not working when sorted in JsTree

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, jstree, jstree-dnd

I am using JsTree library for generate tree view using following JSON object.

```
var data = [{"id":1,"parent":"#","text":"Items for Sale","icon":"fa fa-folder","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":1},"a_attr":[]},{"id":2,"parent":"#","text":"Service","icon":"fa fa-folder","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":2},"a_attr":[]},{"id":3,"parent":"#","text":"Vacancies","icon":"fa fa-folder","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":3},"a_attr":[]},{"id":4,"parent":"#","text":"Rent Property or Vehicle","icon":"fa fa-folder","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":4},"a_attr":[]},{"id":5,"parent":8,"text":"Electronics","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":2},"a_attr":[]},{"id":6,"parent":8,"text":"Cars and Vehicles","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":1},"a_attr":[]},{"id":7,"parent":1,"text":"Property","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":1},"a_attr":[]},{"id":8,"parent":1,"text":"Home and Gardens","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":2},"a_attr":[]},{"id":9,"parent":1,"text":"Fassion Health and Beauty","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":3},"a_attr":[]},{"id":10,"parent":1,"text":"Hobbies Sports and Kids","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":4},"a_attr":[]},{"id":14,"parent":2,"text":"Trade Services","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":1},"a_attr":[]},{"id":15,"parent":2,"text":"Domestic Service","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":2},"a_attr":[]},{"id":16,"parent":2,"text":"Events and Entertainment","icon":"fa fa-file","state":{"opened":true,"disabled":false,"selected":false},"li_attr":{"order-num":3},"a_attr":[]}];
```

I am trying to sort the tree view nodes using **"order-num"** value and then manually change the sort order by drag and drop. Drag and drop must be allowed only within the dragging node's first parent UL. But the problem is when sorted, drag and drop doesn't work. Here is my JsTree code.

```
$('#categories-wrapper').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': data,
            "check_callback": true
        },
        "plugins": ["dnd", "sort"],
        'sort': function (a, b) {
            a1 = this.get_node(a);
            b1 = this.get_node(b);

            return (a1.li_attr['order-num'] > b1.li_attr['order-num']) ? 1 : -1;
        }
});
```

Comment: What is the exact behavior you're looking for? It seems like sort is interfering with the dragn and drop;if I disable sort I can drag and drop within the first ul (i don't think you want this though). I created a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uq26jqwh/4/

Comment: @JonathanChaplin, Thanks. I also need to change the nodes order manually by drag and drop nodes only inside the dragging node's first parent ul.  I edited the question for explain the exact behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: try this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/nn5GaA6WhXE

Answer (score 1):

As this solution https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/nn5GaA6WhXE did not work for me I found another one. It is not perfect but it worked for me.

```
$('.jstree').on('ready.jstree', (e, data) => {
   data.instance.sort = () => {};
});
```

The trick is to disable sorting after initial rendering. This is what the code does. After tree was rendered sort is not longer needed. So just put empty function in `sort`.

Make sure to place this code before `$('.jstree').jstree()`.